# Inserting a node in nth position in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node *link;
};
node *head = NULL;

void insert(int data, int n)
{
    node *temp = new node();
    temp->data = data;

    if (n == 1)
    {
        temp->link = head;
        head = temp;
    }

    else 
    {
        node* ptr = head;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
            ptr = ptr->link;
        temp->link = ptr->link;
        ptr->link = temp;
    }
}

void print()
{
    cout << "list is: ";
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    insert(2, 1);
    insert(3, 2);
    insert(4, 3);
    insert(5, 4);
    insert(6, 5);

    print();
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code to implement insertion in a linked list at nth position. The data and position are being passed from the main position.

I am not getting what is the possible error I have made, it has something to do with the `for loop`.

Its not executing, however if i make the following change:

```
for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
```

it works fine.

Comment: Perfect point to start your program in the debugger, step through the code line by line and inspect what exactly happens.

Comment: You should check if ptr is null before dereferencing.

Comment: If you need to insert into n-th position then most probably you should not use linked list

Comment: You didn't ask a question. And if "it works fine" with the given change, why ask one in the first place? Did you not understand the change *you* made? If not, why did you make it? Spaghetti programming (throwing random noodles at the wall in hopes one will eventually stick) isn't really beneficial.

Comment: You leak all of the memory that you allocate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `insert(2,1)` works fine. So you have linked list like this

```
(2)->NULL
 |
head
```

In the second insert, Lets follow the code,

```
1. else 
2. {
3.    node* ptr = head;
4.    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
5.        ptr = ptr->link;
6.    temp->link = ptr->link;
7.    ptr->link = temp;
8. }
```

Line 3, `ptr` points to `head`. `n` is 2

```
(2)->NULL
 |
head
 |
ptr
```

Line 4, `1 <= (2-1)` is `true` because `1 == 1`, so for loop runs once

Line 5, `ptr` moves one step, so it points to `NULL`

```
(2)->NULL
 |    |
head  |
      |
     ptr
```

Line 6, `ptr->link` is called, which is `NULL->link`. So it crashes here.

---

When you do `for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)`, `n` is 2, so `0 < (2-2)` is `false`, so it runs fine. Note: Works only when insert calls are made in order like your example. If they are called in wrong order, it wont work.

Changing Line 6 to `temp->link = ptr;`, should also work without changing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

"Inserting a node in nth position in a linked list" :

Use a `std::list` rather than rolling your own. Then use [std::list::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert).

Also; consider just using a `std:: vector` instead. A list is a *terrible* (pointer chasing, cache miss inducing) data structure to use on modern CPUs. A `std::vector` will almost always beat it (regardless of what your textbooks say about theoretical performance).

Comment: In addition, O(1) insert quickly becomes O(N) if you have to find the insertion point.

Comment: It seems to be some excercise, imlementing own linked list, so your answer might be not as useful as you think.

Comment: @DenisSablukov If that is the case, then OP *should* have made that clear in the question.

Comment: @user4581301 Inserting into a linked list is also linear if you have to **find** the insertion point. It's only constant if you have a pointer (iterator, reference) to the position.